# Should I use requestAnimationFrame to fade in several elements? To achieve 60fps animation?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Trying to maintain 60 fps animation. Currently, I'm getting a lot of spikes of slow frames that are happening at like 30~ fps and the choppiness is noticeable to my eye.

**Significant Edits: Throwing out old obsolete code, adding in new code with explanation**

```
    fadeIn: function(ele){
        raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            console.log(ele);
            var opacity = 0;
            function increase () {
                opacity += 0.05;
                if (opacity >= 1){
                    // complete
                    ele.style.opacity = 1;
                    return true;
                }
                ele.style.opacity = opacity;
                requestAnimationFrame(increase);
            }
            increase();
        });
    },

    fadeInElements: function(elements, properties, speed, delay){
        var raf;
        var ele;

        for (i = 0; i < properties.length; i++){
            ele = elements[properties[i]];
            console.log('outside loop ' + ele);
            instance.fadeIn(ele);
        }
    },
```

My new code is above. It is successfully:

- Iterating through several elements (each as `ele`) and then calling `fadeIn(ele)`
- So, all elements fade in.
- However, I want a `50ms` delay between each "fade in" (each triggering of `fadeIn()` on a new element

Comment: Why are you even dubious about that? `rAF` is *the* answer to this kind of problems, you should have gone for that from the beginning. I don't know what exacly you want to achieve with this animation, so I can't really help with your code, but you certainly need a different approach. Maybe if you're a bit clearer...

Comment: Here's an [example](https://psenough.github.io/mdt9k_s01e01/) of a simple animation that uses `requestAnimationFrame` --- and it plays audio, too! :)  Here's the [GitHub](https://github.com/psenough/mdt9k_s01e01/) as well.  (Not by me --- just passing along since I think it's a good sample.)

Comment: can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: @MaxArt Alright I believe you are definitely right, I'm just super clueless at learning how to do `rAF` "with a delay," if that makes sense. To simply my goal as much as possible, I want a function that I pass an array of HTML elements. Then the function fades in each element one after another by setting their opacity to 1, then waiting some `delay` ms, then setting the next element opacity to 1. The animation happens automatically because the elements have set `transition: .33s opacity ease-out`. Is this any clearer?

Comment: [This question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109450/interpolation-using-cubic-bezier-curves) on GameDev.SE may also be helpful to you.

Comment: One last thought!  Don't delay between frames.  Frame rate is fixed.  Instead, compute what the opacity should be for whatever frame you're at, and then draw that frame.  Use `(new Date()).getTime()` to get the time, e.g., as [here](https://github.com/psenough/mdt9k_s01e01/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L123).  Save the time at the start of your animation, get the current time each frame, and compute what the opacities of your elements should be based on how much time has elapsed in the animation.  Good luck!

Comment: @cxw thank you! that logically sounds like a much more reliable solution hm -- will have to experiment now to try to get the syntax to work! I just struggle with this because it seems to involve some recursion? Which I have always been weak at :(

Comment: @cxw Attempted a new try, it's really bad and I'm getting a serious error lol that I really don't understand why -- I got this error last night too in some of my attempts.. Would you mind taking a look at the edit to the very bottom of my OP?

Comment: @guest271314 I just edited the entire post to have the code I have running now... not sure if it helps since it's not a JSfiddle yet

Comment: You can optinonally use CSS animations/transitions which will hand over the timings to the browser's internals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good news is that it's not actually recursion — it's more like a timeout.  You provide a function that draws a frame, and the browser calls it for you.

Here's an answer showing excerpts from a [complete JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sk8s7jfr/3/).  It doesn't try to replicate your exact code, but instead tries to explain what you need to know so you can adapt your code accordingly.  The code was written to be easy to understand, so I'm sure there are other ways to do it faster!

This answer works from the top level down, which means I describe the end of the JSFiddle source and work my way backwards.  I personally think this makes it easier to understand than does starting with the details.

1. You need to start the animation somewhere.  So the very last thing in the JSFiddle is

   ```
   window.requestAnimationFrame(eachFrame);    //start the animation
   ```

   This will call a function called `eachFrame()` when it's time for the next frame, e.g,. on the next multiple of 60 times per second.  It will only do it once, though.
2. You need `eachFrame()` to keep track of where we are in the animation.

   ```
   var startTime = -1.0;  // -1 = a flag for the first frame.
   function eachFrame()
   {
     // Render this frame ------------------------
     if(startTime<0) {
       // very first frame (because of the -1.0): save the start time.
       startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
       render(0.0);
         // the parameter to render() is the time within the
         // animation.
     } else {
       // every frame after the first: subtract the saved startTime
       // to determine the current time.
       render( (new Date()).getTime() - startTime );
     }

     // Now we're done rendering one frame. ------
     //Start the timer to call this function again
     //when it's time for the next frame.
     window.requestAnimationFrame(eachFrame);  

   }; //eachFrame
   ```

   `eachFrame()` determines what the current time is with respect to the beginning of the animation.  [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) gives you the time in milliseconds.

   The other thing `eachFrame()` does is to call `window.requestAnimationFrame(eachFrame);` again.  This isn't recursion.  Instead, `eachFrame()` will finish running, and then after that, the next time a frame comes around, the browser will call `eachFrame()` again.
3. The last function you need is something to actually draw the frame!  That is `render(current time)`.  Assume that, e.g., `head1` and `head2` refer to two heading elements you want to animate, e.g., `<h1>` elements declared in your HTML.  The `clamp(x)` function returns `x` but clamped below at 0 and above at 1.

   ```
   function render(currTime)
   { // *** Put your rendering code here ***
     // How opaque should head1 be?  Its fade started at currTime=0.
     var opacity1 = clamp(currTime/FADE_DURATION);
       // over FADE_DURATION ms, opacity goes from 0 to 1

     // How opaque should head2 be?
     var opacity2 = clamp( (currTime-FADE_SPACING)/FADE_DURATION );
       // fades in, but doesn't start doing it until
       // FADE_SPACING ms have passed.

     // Apply the changes
     head1.style.opacity = opacity1;
     head2.style.opacity = opacity2;
   } //render
   ```

   In `render()`, you figure out opacity based on the current time.  You don't have to worry about delaying between frames, because `requestAnimationFrame` handles that for us.  You stagger the transitions by offsetting the time.  In this example, `opacity1` depends on `currTime` and `opacity2` depends on `currTime` minus a constant `FADE_SPACING`, so the opacity change for element 2 will start later than the opacity change for element 1 by `FADE_SPACING` ms.

The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sk8s7jfr/3/) has all the details filled in.  It animates the opacity of two `<h1>` elements, with a spacing between the beginning of the animation for each element.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Can't tell you how much I appreciate such a thorough answer, thanks so much. I wish all tutorials (or code for that matter) were written as clearly as this! I think I will finally understand how to write RAF functions on my own after I've properly tinkered with your code (just looked at it but of course I have to re-write it to properly learn!) Thanks so much again, I actually most likely would not have figured this out on my own otherwise.

Comment: Glad to be able to help! :)  <blatant plug> I'm going to put an expanded version on my blog and would welcome further questions here or there :) .  Link in my profile.  <end of ridiculous self-advertising>

Comment: By all means, this is a very helpful answer. Feel free to link your blog post when it's up, in your Answer itself. As far as I know, self-promotion is okay as long as it's clearly-identified as such and connected to a high-value answer, which this is.